# Listagg function with rep substr function

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, listagg

RAW DATA:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
Ajay    G1  B1  10.201.131.27
Ajay    G1  B2  10.201.131.27
Ajay    G1  B1  10.201.131.28
Ajay    G1  B2  10.201.131.28
Ajay    G1  B1  10.201.131.29
Ajay    G1  B2  10.201.131.29
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT using Oracle 10g

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
Ajay    G1  B1,B2   10.201.131.27,10.201.131.28, 10.201.131.29
```

Would be very glad if someone is able to help.

### Query I used:

```
select * from (select 
Col1,
Col2,
substr(regexp_replace(','||(LISTAGG(( CASE WHEN T1.COl3 IS NULL OR TRIM( T1.COl3 ) ='' THEN NULL ELSE T1.COl3   END), ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY T1.COl1 )), '(,[^,]+)(\1)+', '\1'),2) as COl3 ,
substr(regexp_replace(','||(LISTAGG(( CASE WHEN T1.COl4 IS NULL OR TRIM( T1.COl4 ) ='' THEN NULL ELSE  T1.COl4   END), ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY T1.COl1 )), '(,[^,]+)(\1)+', '\1'),2) as COl4 ,
from T1
Group by 
Col1
)abc
```

---

### The OUTOPUT I GOT is below,

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
Ajay    G1  B1,B2   10.201.131.27
Ajay    G1  B1,B2   10.201.131.28
Ajay    G1  B1,B2   10.201.131.29
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To eliminate duplicates from `LISTAGG` you may use in `Oracle 10` the `row_number` function to define the *order of the duplication*.

In the next step you pass to the `LISTAGG` function only the *first* duplicated (row_number = 1), all higher duplicates are reset to `NULL` that is ignored by `LISTAGG`.

Here the query

```
with t2 as (
select 
COL1, COL2,
COL3,
row_number() over (partition by col1, col2, col3 order by null) as rn3,
COL4,
row_number() over (partition by col1, col2, col4 order by null) as rn4
from t)
select
  COL1, COL2,
  listagg(case when rn3 = 1 then COL3 end,',') within group (order by COL3) COL3,
  listagg(case when rn4 = 1 then COL4 end,',') within group (order by COL4) COL4
from t2
group by COL1, COL2
```

result

```
COL1,   COL2, COL3, COL4
Ajay    G1  B1,B2   10.201.131.27,10.201.131.28,10.201.131.29
```

Note that *this approach is far superior that the afterwards elimination with  `REGEXP` as for non-trivial data you to often encounters `ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long` before you can start the elimination*.

Note also, that you can upgrade to Oracle 19 (which can be considered overdue from the point of Oracle 10) and you may use the feature [`LISTAGG (DISTINCT`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/20/sqlrf/LISTAGG.html#GUID-B6E50D8E-F467-425B-9436-F7F8BF38D466) with the same affect without the need of elimination duplicates. This version also elegantl yhandles the `owerflow`  problems.

Comment: This really makes sense ...thanks for your effort on this

Answer (score 1):

```
with t (Col1,    Col2,    Col3,    Col4) as (
select 'Ajay',    'G1',  'B1',  '10.201.131.27' from dual union all
select 'Ajay',    'G1',  'B2',  '10.201.131.27' from dual union all
select 'Ajay',    'G1',  'B1',  '10.201.131.28' from dual union all
select 'Ajay',    'G1',  'B2',  '10.201.131.28' from dual union all
select 'Ajay',    'G1',  'B1',  '10.201.131.29' from dual union all
select 'Ajay',    'G1',  'B2',  '10.201.131.29' from dual)
, t1 as (
select Col1, Col2
, listagg(Col3, ',') within group (order by Col3) x
, listagg(Col4, ',') within group (order by Col4) y
from t
group by Col1, Col2
)
select Col1, Col2
, rtrim(regexp_replace(x || ',', '([^,]+,)\1+', '\1'), ',') Col3_
, rtrim(regexp_replace(y || ',', '([^,]+,)\1+', '\1'), ',') Col4_
from t1
;

COL1  CO  COL3_                           COL4_                                                       
----  --  ------------------------------  ------------------------------------------------------------
Ajay  G1  B1,B2                           10.201.131.27,10.201.131.28,10.201.131.29
```

I was showing it in two steps, but it can be in one step as well.

```
select Col1, Col2
, rtrim(regexp_replace(listagg(Col3, ',') within group (order by Col3) || ',', '([^,]+,)\1+', '\1'), ',') Col3_
, rtrim(regexp_replace(listagg(Col4, ',') within group (order by Col4) || ',', '([^,]+,)\1+', '\1'), ',') Col4_
from t
group by Col1, Col2
;
```